# Nodejs database monitoring

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb

I have a `Node.js` server and a `mongodb` database, in the databse i store users to-do tasks, each task has a start time, every hour i have to check the users tasks and send a notify if the task is near to the start time.

Right now I do this with a js script that

- it's permanently active
- every 60 minutes get the users tasks from the db with mongoose
- with a for loop checks if each task is near to start
- if they are it sends the notify.

My question is: *there is a right way for to this type of tasks?*

I think that the method that i'm using is resource consuming more than it should be.

Comment: You could possibly employ some inner node scheduling with `node-cron` and just schedule when the notifies should be sent, but that depends on how often you tasks and other factors. You don't explain, why part of your process you consider so resource consuming.

Comment: @px1mp Actually the process is only this, it get the datas, view them and if needed send an sms. This one of my first times deploying an app on server and 
I read that making listners is much resource consuming, since I did it by hand i was wondering if there was something better and more 'correct' to do. I'll check node-cron thanks!

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by *making listeners*, but writing code that just listens to events (the only think I can think of when you mention listeners) is the way programming is done in node.js .